# What are some decent apps for Hasse diagrams?

Tags: technology-in-education, software, topology, graph-theory, combinatorics

What options are out there for software that supports interactively constructing, editing, and manipulating [Hasse diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)? Their semantics is significantly constrained, so garden-variety *Let’s-draw-DAGs* apps aren’t all that useful.

Desirable features would include

1. automatic monitoring and guided maintenance of transitive reduction
2. dynamic enforcement of the constraint that whenever $a \leq b$, the drawing of $a$ is never above the drawing of $b$. Perhaps if the user tries to drag $a$ up past $b$, the app rigidly shoves the entire drawing of the induced subposet with minimum $b$ upward to make room.
3. support for such fairly standardized queries as “Highlight the (subposet induced by) elements above (resp. below) $x$,” “Highlight the elements incomparable to $x$,” “Highlight all the covers of (resp. elements covered by) $x$,” “Highlight the meets (resp. joins) of $x$ and $y$,” and “Highlight successively the maximal (or, in particular, maximum) chains (resp. antichains),” as well as “Show me all the critical pairs.”
4. support for such more general queries as “Here’s a substructure I’m interested in; show me all of the induced subposets isomorphic to it.”
5. Support for labels and annotations in $\LaTeX$ syntax.
6. And of course, an `export as PDF` function.

Some of these desired features are computationally intensive. So clearly, as the size of the poset grew, such an app’s performance would inevitably become sluggish. But it would be very useful to have a tool with these capabilities even for only smallish posets.

Answer (score 2):

This is such a niche request that I doubt you're going to be able to find an off-the-shelf app that does everything you want (though I'd love to be proven wrong).

That said, Mathematica has a `HasseDiagram` function that can be used to draw and manipulate Hasse Diagrams: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HasseDiagram/

While it doesn't have all the bells and whistles that you mention, looking at the variety of examples in that link, I get the sense it might be feasible to write a wrapper around that function to do all the things that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use Sage. Sage is a mathematics toolkit built upon Python and is extremely powerful, if occasionally slow due to its generality. The [documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/posets/hasse_diagram.html) of Hasse diagrams doesn't include how to view them, but there are many methods to do so. If an object is a [Poset object](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/posets/posets.html) in Sage, then the .plot() method creates a visual of it.

There is a [discussion question](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/63200/latex-for-hasse-diagram-of-poset-not-properly-laid-out/) on the Sage forums which asks about how to generate tikz $\LaTeX$ for the presentation of a Hasse diagram. The solution, pulled from this discussion post, appears to be as follows:

> - Install sage, compiled from source.
> - Install graphviz to the OS (using the appropriate package manager)
> - Install dot2tex to the Sage directory using ./sage --pip install dot2tex
> - Define a poset object, named B, in any appropriate manner.
> - Call view(B, debug=True)

There are many methods for editing and highlighting, though I don't think they are interactive in the way you want.